# button in cell with weblink

Tags: ios, ios7, uibutton

I am trying to add a simple button to a custom cell that has a web link. I added the button in  story board and associated it with houseLink. Here is my view.M file where I call the button from the custom cell.

```
    #import "IBSecondViewController.h"
    #import "C21TableCell.h"


    @interface IBSecondViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation IBSecondViewController
    {
        NSArray *thumbnails;

    }
    @synthesize data;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //Initialize House Array
        data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2109 E Avon Cricle, Hayden Lake, ID", @"703 E Garden, Coeur d' Alene, ID", nil];

        _bedroom = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"3", @"4", nil];

        // Initialize thumbnails
        thumbnails = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"stockHouse.png", @"stockHouse2.png", nil];

    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view ddata source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [data count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"C21TableCell";

        C21TableCell *cell = (C21TableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"C21TableCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        cell.addressLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.bedroomLabel.text = [_bedroom objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NOT SURE HOW TO CALL THE BUTTON HERE



        return cell;
    }

    -(void) buttonpressed:(UIButton *)sender {
        NSString* launchUrl = @"http://apple.com/";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: launchUrl]];
    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return 78;
    }

    @end
```

C21TableCell.H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface C21TableCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *addressLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *bedroomLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *thumbnailImageView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *homeLink;


@end
```

C21TableCell.M

```
#import "C21TableCell.h"

@implementation C21TableCell

@synthesize addressLabel = _nameLabel;
@synthesize bedroomLabel = _bedroomLabel;
@synthesize thumbnailImageView = _thumbnailImageView;
@synthesize homeLink = homeLink;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add target to button action when you create cell

```
[cell.homeLink addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonpressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Worked perfect. I am new to iOS so was calling it just `cell.homelink` no brackets.